# Emacs adds 2;rgb:0000/0000/00 to beginning of buffer

Tags: python, shell, emacs

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.4.1 and every time I open a file using the -nw flag on a shell or python script this text gets added to the beginning of the buffer: "2;rgb:0000/0000/00". I don't see this with C or C++ files for some reason. This is really slowing me down because every time I modify a .py or .sh file I have to remember to delete this and it's rather annoying.

Comment: Does this happen if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If no, recursively bisect your init file until you find the culprit. If yes, recursively bisect whatever files you are loading that deal with shell or python editing modes. You can use `comment-region` to comment out blocks of text (`C-u` to uncomment).

Comment: Good suggestions from Drew. Does this only happen with `-nw`? What terminal or console are you running in? With what shell?

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? I'm guessing it's one of the few that support RGB color (not just a palette of 256), and it's sending some sort of reply to a request it thinks is coming from Emacs. Just a guess, though; I haven't used such terminals and don't know what their color code strings look like, or whether they respond like that.

Comment: This doesn't happen with emacs -Q only with -nw. I'm using xterm for my terminal and bash for my shell. @Drew when you say recursively bisect my init file you are referring to my .emacs file right? I haven't made many additions to it and I'm not sure how I would start debugging it especially since it seems to be a pretty small file.

Comment: Yes, your init file is likely `.emacs` (see (emacs)[`Init File`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html)). If you don't see the problem with `emacs -Q` then something in your init file (or in `site-file`) is causing the problem. It might be something in a file that your init file loads. In any case, recursively bisect the init file (and if necessary any culpable file it loads), to find which part causes the problem.

Comment: Hi, I had a same problem, do you know how to fix?